# How to install ROS2 foxy in a custom arm64 Linux based in Yocto? (Petalinux)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working in a custom Linux project based on Petalinux, which is a Xilinx Linux distro built from Yocto (which uses  OpenEmbedded), I could install ubuntu 20.04 LTS arm64 in this custom project but now I would like to install ROS2 foxy

As I have ubuntu 20.04 my first attempt was this:
https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

but it failed, when tried with ros-foxy-desktop or ros-foxy-ros-base the packages was not found,
when I tried this in my Linux pc with ubuntu 20.04 everything was ok, so I found this:
https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#support-tiers where you explain that for an OpenEmbedded Linux I must use the sources to install ros2 foxy

second attempt: building from sources
https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html

but also failed, when building the project I have an error with this package: mimick_vendor, the package could not be installed and then I got a lot of errors

but then inside the previous link I saw this:

**Oher Linux platforms with varying support levels include:**

Arch Linux, see alternate instructions

Fedora Linux, see alternate instructions

**OpenEmbedded / webOS OSE, see alternate instructions**

so, those are the instructions I should follow?
https://github.com/ros/meta-ros/wiki/OpenEmbedded-Build-Instructions#add-meta-ros-to-an-existing-openembedded-project

or as I have Ubuntu 20.04 I should try to resolve the error in my second attempt?

And, could be this a way to avoid the installation of ros2 in my target board?
https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Cross-compilation.html#cross-compilation
as I understand with this option I could deploy and test my ros2 app in my pc and then build it to use it in my embedded Linux, but I don´t know if this is the correct case to use this tool

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389528/how-to-install-ros2-foxy-in-a-custom-arm64-linux-based-in-yocto?-(petalinux)/) by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My fault, I was using a  32 bits ubuntu distro instead a 64 bits

---

Originally posted by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) with karma: 31 on 2021-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0